# How can I find Client Secret for Google API?

Tags: youtube-data-api

On Youtube API support page [was mentioned](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support) that I may ask question about API here. So...

I have problem with setting up my web service app that uses youtube API for crawling video comments. I try to use Google API client for node.js ([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis#authorizing-and-authenticating) is info about authorization using this client). I cannot find where my **client secret** data is placed. I cannot understand how to get it.

I created both *API key* and *Service account key* - but no client secret info is on my credentials page or on keys detailed info. After registering *Service account key* I got json file with data like *private_key*, *private_key_id* - but no *client secret* was there.

After some time of googling I found button "Select an existing OAuth 2.0 credential" on the page about [OpenID](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect). But I got "This project has no appropriate credentials" after pushing it. I clicked "Credentials page" after it and there were two keys - both, API and Service account key.

Please help me understand how to find the data I need!

**P.S:** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007327/google-api-php-client-invalid-client-secret-json-file) was a question about client secret. Answer contains next quota:

> When you create a web application you will be given a client_id,
>   client_secret, redirect_uri etc

But I got no json files after registering key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's it... I can't understend. It's very strange - I'm sure there was no such option yesterday. Maybe it appeared after I created service account key. Maybe I was too tired.

I'm closing the question. Sorry about so stupid QA)

[image]